# MSDTC Distributed Transaction Coordinator Enabling

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq, msdtc

I've a web server and a separate SQL server. I'm trying to use transaction scope to ensure that SQL queries are completed with my linq queries.

I wrap everything with this

using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())

I want to know where I need to install DTC. Do I need to install it on the IIS 7.5 box AND the SQL server? Do I need to unblock some ports? Are there any security risk in doing so?

I've setup this up once before but don't remember how. If I can't get access to DTC then is there any other way to ensure a lINQ and sql query is atomic?

Comment: vote to move to server fault.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is a duplicate of [Where MSDTC needs to be installed and configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039966/where-msdtc-needs-to-be-installed-in-distributed-transaction-case).

The answer is at both endpoints participating in the transaction, but the security is such that one is outbound and the other is inbound.