# Transaction issue in ASP Classic

Tags: transactions, asp-classic, iis-7.5

I am facing `HTTP 500 error` with classic asp application hosted in `IIS 7.5` server and Windows server 2008.

I have done the below steps.

1. 32 Bit Enabled in App Pool
2. Enable Parent Paths = true
3. MSDTC Security settings updated

Still that is not working with the above changes. But on uninstalling and installing `MSDTC` and doing a `IISRESET` works fine.

Note: ASP page enabled with `Transaction=required` and removing this also works fine.

Comment: 500 just means "internal server error". The possibilities for what is actually causing that are pretty much infinite. Turn on detailed error messages, make sure your browser isn't allowed to think it's smarter than you are, and then, based on the page and line number of the actual error, let us know exactly what code is throwing exactly what error.

Comment: I have enabled it in ASP settings inside IIS 7.5 and also enabled to show friendly error messages in IE, but still it not showing up the actual error. any ideas?

Comment: [How to enable detailed errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2640607/121333), and turn OFF the friggin' "friendly" (code word for "useless") error messages.

Comment: Yes I was having the same issue couple of months ago and removing transaction worked for me too. This happens when your database is not on the same server. I didn't find any reason for transactions so I removed.
I'd suggest to go the IIS logs (C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\) and see the detail error for that particular page.

Comment: Might I ask why you're still using ASP Classic?

Comment: @c-sharp, I could not get anything with logs.

Comment: @Ortund Its an existing application and have to use the same

Comment: Just for background, could someone explain what  the Transaction=required feature is intended to actually do?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open IIS manager and go to ASP section
2. set send error to browser = true
3. remove the default script error message
4. save and restart IIS
5. Uncheck the "Show friendly error message" from browser. If you have performed the above steps you will be able to see the correct error in you browser.

Check the screenshot below

[IIS settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9Bwr.jpg)

What is the error you are seeing in the browser??
Check these below links to configure MSDTC and your DB for transaction and authentication (inbound,outbound). For you description it looks like a authentication and transaction related issue in ASP.

[Where MSDTC needs to be installed in Distributed transaction case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039966/where-msdtc-needs-to-be-installed-in-distributed-transaction-case)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd327979.aspx